# geometric way to determine distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, random-matrices

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix, i.e.
\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 & X_2  \\
X_3 & X_4   \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where the $X_{i}$'s entries i.i.d normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. The problem was to determine the ditribution of $\det(A)$. Now with characteristic function and the law of total expectation I come to the solution, that the distribution function has density $\exp(-|x|)/2$. This was not so difficult.

Now I know that $\det(A)$ is the area of a parallelogram with vertices
\begin{align}
(0,0), (X_{1},X_{2}), (X_{3},X_{4}), (X_{1} + X_{2},X_{3} + X_{4}).
\end{align}

Is there a way to obtain the solution using this geometric way?

Comment: I believe the fourth point of the parallelogram should be $X_1+X_3,$ $X_2+X_4$.

Comment: have you a solution to this problem? I'have solved the problem with characteristic function but it would be interesting to obtain a geometric solution

Comment: Sorry about that. I believe that the idea there will work, but the distributions of the two factors in the product aren't just half-normal. The first one is Chi with 2 df's, and it would take some work to determine the distribution of $X_{4}$ (it might just be half-normal, but I don't know).

Comment: with characteristic function it is very easy, but trying it with annother approach seems to me very difficult

Comment: I think is to difficult to obtain a solution this way